# Solr atomic/in-place update by CSV

Tags: solr

I have a core whose columns come from different sources in CSV format (all having a unique ID)

Source 1:

```
ID,Col1,Col2
1,33,77
```

Source 2:

```
ID,Col3,Col4
1,8,9
```

Source 3:

```
ID,Col5,Col6
1,0,100
```

Uploading CSV will overwrite the entire row including missing columns.

```
url 'http://localhost:8983/solr/Data/update?commit=true&escape=\&encapsulator="&fieldnames=ID,Col1,Col2' -T source1.csv -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
url 'http://localhost:8983/solr/Data/update?commit=true&escape=\&encapsulator="&fieldnames=ID,Col3,Col4' -T source2.csv -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/csv'
```

Is there a way to use Atomic or In-Place update to add/update specific columns?

I cannot merge CSVs and I cannot create different cores and merge to one final core.

I use Solr 8.9.0 on Linux.

Comment: Solr supports [atomic updates](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/updating-parts-of-documents.html), can you at least control the way you call the `/update` handler? Apart from this, the only thing i can remember is the [overwrite parameter](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/updating-parts-of-documents.html) when calling the `/update` handler but i really don't know what's the side effect of setting it to `false` (it's `true` by default) in your use case.

Comment: @nitrin0 setting `overwrite=false` skips the update if the Unique ID exists.